# PHP SELECT parameter syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'd like to `SELECT` a field called `device_token` in the statement below. My main goal is to select the token and store it in a new variable.

```
    $result = query("SELECT IdPhoto, title, IdUser FROM photos p ORDER BY IdPhoto DESC LIMIT 50") ;
```

Here is the body of the function and what I've tried:

```
function stream($IdPhoto=0, $token) {

if ($IdPhoto==0) {

    //Here's where I want to grab the device_token
    $result = query("SELECT device_token, IdPhoto, device_token, title, IdUser FROM photos p ORDER BY IdPhoto DESC LIMIT 50", $token) ;

} else {
    //do the same as above, but just for the photo with the given id
    $result = query("SELECT IdPhoto, title, l.IdUser, username FROM photos p JOIN login l ON (l.IdUser = p.IdUser) WHERE p.IdPhoto='%d' LIMIT 1", $IdPhoto);

}

if (!$result['error']) {
    // if no error occured, print out the JSON data of the 
    // fetched photo data
    print json_encode($result);
} else {
    //there was an error, print out to the iPhone app
    errorJson('Photo stream is broken');
}
}
```

Is the `($IdPhoto==0)` parameter is getting in the way of the `$token` variable? If so how can one properly do these things?

1. Select the `device_token`
2. Store it in a new variable called `$token`
3. Add the `$token` parameter to function name

Comment: what is there on login table? if you run this query directly on the DB it returns what you expect?

Comment: Add the two tables' definitions.

Comment: in login there is `username` , `password` , `IdUser`. Yes, the above query works as it should

Comment: what do you mean @jarlh ?

Comment: I just wanted to see the tables' columns (and their data types, constraints etc.)

Comment: is device_token binary? How do you retrieve it in PHP?

Comment: How do you try to process device_token field in the php code after running the sql query? The 1st of the 3 attempst is incorrect btw, a comma is missing after device_token field. I do not see any issues with the other 2, though. Hence my question again: how do you process the results of the query?

Comment: I try to show it in a UILabel that currently shows the users's username. Updated: added the missing `,`

Comment: The query also gets photo information from the database and shows it in the app successfully. The query shows the last 50 photos in the database in the photos table. When I add one of the three methods, no photos show at all for some reason...

Comment: what you get from this `SELECT device_token, IdPhoto, title, IdUser FROM photos p ORDER BY IdPhoto DESC LIMIT 50`

Comment: @RohitAwasthi it shows the stream including the photos but not the username

Comment: no, does it shows device_token?

Comment: Hey @RohitAwasthi I just tried to connect the device token to the class I want to show it in, and it looks like it will need a modification to select it correctly. Have you any ideas? Right now it shows as nil.

Comment: @user3233623 and that UILabel can show username or title correctly? If yes, then will this UILabel keep showing username or title correctly if you change username or title to "utf8-general-cl" ? test this.

Comment: and/or create column device_token2 "latin1-swedish-ci" and test this column in label

Comment: Yes the UILabel can show the username, title, IdUser and IdPhoto. When I changed the username to utf8_general_ci the label reads as null

Answer (score 2):

Use this way:

```
$result = query("SELECT photos.device_token, IdPhoto, title, l.IdUser, username FROM photos p JOIN login l ON (l.IdUser = p.IdUser) ORDER BY IdPhoto DESC LIMIT 50");
```

Probably you have `device_token` in both tables, and the results is getting the empty `device_token` from the other table.